# Why doesn't JAXB generate setters for Lists

Tags: java, jaxb, getter-setter

When I generate JAXB classes from an XSD, the elements with `maxOccurs="unbounded"` gets a getter method generated for them, but no setter method, as follows:

```
/**
 * Gets the value of the element3 property.
 * 
 * <p>
 * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
 * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
 * returned list will be present inside the JAXB object.
 * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the element3 property.
 * 
 * <p>
 * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
 * <pre>
 *    getElement3().add(newItem);
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 * <p>
 * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
 * {@link Type }
 * 
 * 
 */
public List<Type> getElement3() {
    if (element3 == null) {
        element3 = new ArrayList<Type>();
    }
    return this.element3;
}
```

The method comment makes it crystal clear on how can I use it, but my question is as follows: 
**Why doesn't JAXB just generate a setter, following the Java Beans rules?** I know I can write the setter method myself, but is there any advantage to the approach suggested in the generated getter method?

This is my XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/DoTransfer/" targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/DoTransfer/">

    <element name="CollectionTest" type="tns:CollectionTest"></element>

    <complexType name="CollectionTest">
        <sequence>
            <element name="element1" type="string" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"></element>
            <element name="element2" type="boolean" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"></element>
            <element name="element3" type="tns:type" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1" nillable="true"></element>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>


    <complexType name="type">
        <sequence>
            <element name="subelement1" type="string" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"></element>
            <element name="subelement2" type="string" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0"></element>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
</schema>
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Here is the justification from the JAXB specification - page 60.

> Design Note – There is no setter method for a List property. The
>   getter returns  the List by reference. An item can be added to the
>   List returned by the getter  method using an appropriate method
>   defined on java.util.List. **Rationale  for this design in JAXB 1.0 was
>   to enable the implementation to wrapper the list  and be able to
>   perform checks as content was added or removed from the List.**

So if the implementation of the List was overriding add/remove to perform validation, replacing that 'special' List with (for instance) an ArrayList would defeat these checks.

Comment: Unfortunately without a setter, other components like BlazeDS won't recognise `getItems()` as part of a property and will fall back to the field name (which is protected) and end up passing on a null no matter what was in the list. Adding a setter (one that calls getItems, clears it, and adds the new values) resolves this issue.

Comment: Frankly, I think that's a serious violation of the way Java beans are supposed to work. I would be fine with JAXB attempting to call .add(), when it sees a collection returned by a bean property that has no setter. But, if I defined a setter, it really should assume I've done for a reason and I damn expect it to not been bypassed, and sometime I even return unmodifiable collection wrappers, to force people to not mess up with my internals. Sorry for the rant, but this bug has already wasted two days of my time.

Comment: Apart from many tools not able find setters (as they assume Java Beans rules), major drawback I find in my project is: lot of places `List` getters are called which automatically leads to their initailization to `Empty` list and then while marshalling I have to configure not to send empty list. This disallows me to differentiate the case when I deliberately want to set a property to Empty list. I have a use case when `Empty` list is set, delete clear the list

Answer (score 31):

Link for : [No setter for list](http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/section_2_2_7-Defining-a-List-of-Integers.html)

> The code in the getter method ensures that the List is
>   created. There is no corresponding **setter** which means that all
>   additions or deletions of list elements have to be made on the **"live"**
>   list.

As the quote says that there is no setter as when you use the getter method it insures that a new instance of the list is initialized if not present.

And after that when you have to add or remove anything you will have to use

```
getElement3().add(Type);
```

**UPDATE** : Difference in marshalling for `null` and empty list

Example where list is `null`

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "list-demo")
public class ListDemo {

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "list")
    @XmlElement(name = "list-item")
    private List<String> list;

}
```

OUTPUT will be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<list-demo/>
```

Example where list is **empty**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "list-demo")
public class ListDemo {

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "list")
    @XmlElement(name = "list-item")
    private List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

}
```

OUTPUT will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<list-demo>
    <list/>
</list-demo>
```

Comment: I still don't get the idea why would JAXB care to **insures that a new instance of the list is initialized if not present**!!! why would it care, JAXB works exactly the same if a list value was `null` or an empty list. and preventing `NullPointerException`s here is out of JAXB scope IMO.

Comment: For JAXB null and empty list is **different**. In the following way: If the list is `null` then you would not find that element in the `xml` generated, but if the list is of 0 size then there would be an xml element `<list/>` present in the xml. So they both are different.

Comment: if the `nillable` property is true in the `xsd` then it should not generate that `null` check. AFAIK.

Comment: I have updated the answer to show you the difference between null and empty list

Comment: I see, the `@XmlElementWrapper` did the trick. However, JAXB does not generate it by default and actually it also uses field access type by default, so initializing the list in the getter wouldn't affect the marshalling... my point anyway is about breaking the Java Bean rules by not generating a setter

Comment: But what should I do if I need to check list and if the size is 0 set null instead of list? I've got some xml validations on soap service which I cannot modify and if one list is presented another should be null.

Answer (score 5):

Agree with Patrick's concern above.  If I was coding to the generated java classes directly I'd be happy to oblige, but I'm using an introspective tool expects either a setter or a directly accessible member.
Had success using a plugin to XJC from 
https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics/wiki/JAXB2-Setters-Plugin
and adding a -B-Xsetter argument to wsimport

Answer (score 2):

One can write their own `XJC plugin` for their specific requirement.

In this example one is trying to add an `id` field of type `long` in every generated java file from `xjc`:

```
package com.ricston;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.xml.sax.ErrorHandler;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import com.sun.codemodel.JBlock;
import com.sun.codemodel.JCodeModel;
import com.sun.codemodel.JFieldVar;
import com.sun.codemodel.JMethod;
import com.sun.codemodel.JMod;
import com.sun.codemodel.JType;
import com.sun.codemodel.JVar;
import com.sun.tools.xjc.BadCommandLineException;
import com.sun.tools.xjc.Options;
import com.sun.tools.xjc.Plugin;
import com.sun.tools.xjc.outline.ClassOutline;
import com.sun.tools.xjc.outline.Outline;

public class XJCPlugin extends Plugin {

  public final static String ID = "id";
    public final static JType LONG_TYPE = new JCodeModel().LONG;
    public final static String ID_GETTER = "getId";
    public final static JType VOID_TYPE = new JCodeModel().VOID;
    public final static String ID_SETTER = "setId";

    @Override
    public String getOptionName() {
        return "Xexample-plugin";
    }

    @Override
    public int parseArgument(Options opt, String[] args, int i)
            throws BadCommandLineException, IOException {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsage() {
        return "  -Xexample-plugin    :  xjc example plugin";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean run(Outline model, Options opt, ErrorHandler errorHandler)
            throws SAXException {

        for (ClassOutline classOutline : model.getClasses()) {
            JFieldVar globalId = classOutline.implClass.field(JMod.PRIVATE,
                    LONG_TYPE, ID);

            JMethod idGetterMethod = classOutline.implClass.method(JMod.PUBLIC,
                    LONG_TYPE, ID_GETTER);
            JBlock idGetterBlock = idGetterMethod.body();
            idGetterBlock._return(globalId);

            JMethod idSetterMethod = classOutline.implClass.method(JMod.PUBLIC,
                    VOID_TYPE, ID_SETTER);
            JVar localId = idSetterMethod.param(LONG_TYPE, "_" + ID);
            JBlock idSetterBlock = idSetterMethod.body();
            idSetterBlock.assign(globalId, localId);
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Full example [here](http://archive.ricston.com/blog/xjc-plugin/).

Another example here:

https://blog.jooq.org/2018/02/19/how-to-implement-your-own-xjc-plugin-to-generate-tostring-equals-and-hashcode-methods/

Their are plugins available for generating `hashCode`, `equals`, `setters-for-list` at [github](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics/wiki) too.

**References:**

Answer to a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51304471/jaxb-edit-list-getter) I had asked.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is here looking for a way to get rid of those annoying lazy initializers in XJC-generated code... In my Maven POM, this goes under `<build><plugins>`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>remove-jaxb-generated-lazy-initializers</id>
            <phase>process-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <target if="${remove-jaxb-generated-lazy-initializers}">
                    <echo message="Running 'replaceregexp' target on generated sources..."/>
                    <echo message="This removes JAXB-generated lazy initializers from collection accessors."/>
                    <replaceregexp match="if \([\w_]+ == null\) \{\s+[\w_]+ = new ArrayList&lt;[\w_]+&gt;\(\);\s+\}\s+" replace="" flags="g">
                        <fileset dir="${project.build.directory}/generated-sources" includes="**/*.java"/>
                    </replaceregexp>
                </target>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

For setters, I'm also adding `@lombok.Setter` to certain classes using `org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics-annotate` and a bindings file. Thus the classes end up being standard beans.

I would love to hear it if anyone knows of a less hacky way--e.g., a XJC plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Need to add the dependency inside the plugin. For example as below,

```html
<plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.5</version>
                    <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.andromda.thirdparty.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                        <artifactId>collection-setter-injector</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                    <configuration>
                        <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/epc</schemaDirectory>
                        <arguments>-Xcollection-setter-injector</arguments>
                        <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                        <extension>true</extension>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>generate-java-from-xsd-1</id>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>xjc</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <packageName>${package name}</packageName>
                                <schemaFiles>example.xsd</schemaFiles>
                                <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/epc</schemaDirectory>
                                <bindingFiles>example_1.xjb</bindingFiles>
                                <bindingDirectory>${project.basedir}/generate</bindingDirectory>
                                <staleFile>${project.build.directory}/jaxb2/.xjc1StaleFlag</staleFile>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
              </plugin>
```