# CXF Generate Java Bean Skeleton does not make setters and operation classes

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

I am trying to generate stubs of my model from WSDLs using the Apache CXF 2.7.3 
I see that the stubs created do not have any setters for any complex data type.
I am wondering what may be the cause of this and am looking for a possible fix as this makes the stub unusable.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a duplicate of [Why doesn't JAXB generate setters for Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13913000/why-doesnt-jaxb-generate-setters-for-lists) , where I found a relevant answer :

It is still possible to populate the complex data type (at least in the case of a List), this way :

```
parent.getList().add(aValue);
```

instead of :

```
parent.setList(aListOfValues);
```