# jax-ws wsdl didn't create a set method

Tags: jaxb, wsdl, jax-ws

I have created a wsdl based web service and for some reason one of my elements doesnt have a set method only a get method.

```xml
<xs:element name="Request">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element ref="ns1:source_system"/>
                    <xs:element ref="ns1:target_system"/>
                    <xs:element ref="ns1:message_id"/>
                    <xs:element ref="ns1:message_send_timestamp"/>
                    <xs:element ref="ns1:request_type"/>
                    <xs:element ref="ns1:crm_customer_id"/>
                    <xs:element ref="ns1:crm_request_id"/>
                    <xs:element ref="ns1:donor_id"/>
                    <xs:element ref="ns1:identification_value"/>
                    <xs:element ref="ns1:identification_value_2" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xs:element ref="ns1:identification_value_3" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xs:element ref="ns1:dn_number_item" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

now in my progrem I only have request.getDnNumberItem() and I dont have request.setDnNumberItem(). for all other parameters I have both set and get.

this has happened to me before and somehow got fixed by itself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't JAXB generate setters for Lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13913000/why-doesnt-jaxb-generate-setters-for-lists)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A setter wasn't generated for `dnNumberItem` property because it is a collection property (`maxOccurs="unbounded"`), the others aren't.  You can modify the `List` by accessing it through the getter.

Comment: ty for your answer. what do you mean by "modify the List by accessing it through the getter." , do you mean adding the set method manualy from the getter?

Comment: @susparsy - I mean you can access the `List` with the getter, the you can use the `List` add and remove APIs to modify it.