# JAXB does not create set methods for List

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jaxb, xsd

I have this three types in a XSD:

```
<xs:element name="Account" type="Account"/>
<xs:element name="Operation" type="Operation"/>
<xs:element name="Transaction" type="Transaction"/>

<xs:complexType name="Operation">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="id" type="xs:long"/>
            <xs:element name="type" type="EnumOperationType"/>
            <xs:element name="balance" type="xs:double"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="Transaction">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="id" type="xs:long"/>
            <xs:element name="type" type="EnumOperationType"/>
            <xs:element name="amount" type="xs:double"/>
            <xs:element name="isCredit" type="xs:boolean"/>
            <xs:element name="isDebit" type="xs:boolean"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="Account">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="agencyNumber" type="xs:long"/>
            <xs:element name="accountNumber" type="xs:long"/>
            <xs:element name="owner" type="client:Client"/>
            <xs:element name="balance" type="xs:double"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="Operation"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="Transaction"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
```

When I generate the respectively java objects for them using JABX, I only get `set()` methods for the first four fields: agecy, account, owner and balance.

How to set the lists in a complex object? Do I have to use the ObjectFactory in any way?

Best, Pedro.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do `add` on `addAll` on what is returned from the get method to set the content on the `List` property.

Comment: Thanks. I find this in further search: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13913000/why-doesnt-jaxb-generate-setters-for-lists

Comment: thanks :) We can use The factory generated bu Jaxb too