# Dozer mapping collection in JAXb objects

Tags: java, jaxb, dozer

I have two data set let's consider Data A and Data B generated from JAXb converter. check the below code snippet,

```
// Data A    
public class CompanyA {
    private List<EmployeeA> empList;
}

public class EmployeeA{
    private List<AddressA> addList;
}

public class AddressA{
    private String city;
}

// Data B    
public class CompanyB {
    private List<EmployeeB> empList;
}

public class EmployeeB{
    private List<AddressB> addList;
}

public class AddressB{
    private String city;
}
```

These are generated JaxB Objects with getter [for all] /setter [for non collection fields] (not mentioned in above code). When I tried mapping with Dozer API only the parent object is mapped but will getting null pointer exception while mapping collection.

Tried below mapping approach to resolve the mapping issue,

```
mapping(CompanyA.class, CompanyB.class)
                .fields(field("empList").accessible(true), field("empList").accessible(true));
```

But the flaw in the above approach is that if object contains nested list objects than I have to mention for all the objects with `accessible(true)`

Any other approach that I can try to map all the collection objects, without mentioning all the mapping scenario in mapping configuration.

Comment: Why do you need to set `accessible` to `true` if there is a setter/getter method for each property?

Comment: @araknoid - missed the list part, corrected the question, as those were JaxB generated which cause no setters for collection (like list etc.)

Comment: We faced this issue as well in my office. Check what others have to say [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13913000/why-doesnt-jaxb-generate-setters-for-lists). It might be better just to create the set methods manually rather than trying to find a workaround with Dozer. Because Dozer doesn't take JaxB's issue with collections into account

Comment: @Ray - We continued the same way by generating the setters of object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added below arguments in project pom.xml to generate setters of all object (including collections).

```
<configuration>
    <arguments>
       <argument>-XtoString</argument>
       <argument>-Xsetters</argument>
       <argument>-Xsetters-mode=direct</argument>
    </arguments>
    ....
</configuration>
```

This will forcefully generate setters for all the object from JaxB.